# JavaFX AnchorPane Constraints invisible

Tags: user-interface, javafx, designer, scenebuilder

As mentioned in title, I tried to mess today with JavaFX, but encountered a problem: anchorpane constraints are in tab, which content is invisible for me. Any clues how to fix it?

Manjaro with Intellij.[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make `anchorpane constraints` visible in `scenebuilder` for JavaFX.